# What causes frequent GCP Ubuntu server restarts?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, server, google-compute-engine, restart

I have an **e2-medium** GCP Compute Engine instance running my application, for a while now. It has worked just well, however recently I have experienced frequent auto restarts (3 times in the space of 2 weeks), nothing in the logs points me to the reason for this, but it keeps repeating itself. Can someone please tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

VM's in GCP are not guaranteed to be up 100% of the time. Restarts could be cause by anything from hardware failures to Google performing some maintenance on it's physical servers (hardware repairs or Software patching).